# how to make this statement return correct number of entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using some left-over code since I'm new to Hibernate and DB design. I have the following statement:

```
totalItems = ((Number) criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).
                    uniqueResult()).intValue();
criteria.setProjection(null);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
```

It works with almost every entity except a particular one which has a many-to-many relation. In my case it is `Nominations<-->Nominee<-->Employee` in the DB. In my beans Nomination has a list of Employees to map the relation.

Basically `totalItems` is returning a count of nominees instead of a count of nominations. For example a nomination with 2 nominees counts as 2, instead of 1.

How could I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out. I changed this

```
totalItems = ((Number) criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).
                uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

with this

```
totalItems = ((Number) criteria.setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("id")).
                uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

Basically it is counting distinct now.